# Passing variables to a JRuby application via Tomcat config

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, tomcat, jruby, config

What's the best way to configure variables in a JRuby application that's deployed as a WAR file? The operations group will need to configure database settings and other environment variables depending on where my app is deployed. Since it's a WAR file though they don't have direct access to the database.yml or any of the environment files.

I want to be able to variablize anything they need to configure and have them perhaps put something into the Tomcat app.config/web.config. Is this possible to do? How do you bring those values into JRuby?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So to get parameters from the Tomcat servlet context in JRuby is very simple I discovered:

```
$servlet_context
```

So for example if I had the following defined in the web.xml:

```
# from inside the web.xml context
<context-param>
  <param-value>jdbc:h2:localhost/~/test_db</param-value>
  <param-name>database.url</param-name>
</context-param>
```

You can access the value in JRuby as follows:

```
$servlet_context.getInitParameter("database.url")
```

This would return the string "jdbc:h2:localhost/~/test_db".

Comment: Thanks for this, is useful.  I am deploying multiple wars in different engines and you can add them to in 
`conf/<engine-name>/<host>/context.xml.default` in the different format: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html#Context_Parameters